# door knob for thick interiour door

Tags: doors, doorknob

I'm considering making a well insulated interior door and need to understand the door thickness implications for the getting a door knob.  The door could be upto 3" thick - less if getting a door knob becomes a problem.  I'd like to use a cheap off the shelf knob - possibly adding extensions.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking a question here?  I did a web search for "door knob for thicker doors" and came up with many options, including extension kits and knobs for thicker than normal doors.  Hinges and functionality of a door that thick is another problem to be addressed.

Comment: I did, hence my suggestion of extension, but didn't really understand the options. Is this all I need to adapt one?  https://www.handlesets.com/thick-door-kits/c8599

Comment: visit a hardware store that sells door handle sets .... see what they offer

Comment: @jsotola - thank you for the tip, but why waste an hr or 2 and gasoline when then is a community of creative people with great ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard lockset could be inset into the face of the door, so that 95% has full insulation.  You will also need to consider hinge screw locations in the edge of the door.

Comment: You're suggesting recessed door handles?

Comment: I.e. putting some of your insulation proud of the door handle surface, except where it interferes with the handle. It's not even an inconvenience if you are using lever handles.

Comment: Was definitely over thinking the problem.  I've now have a hollow core door and have attached rigid insulation except near the door handle.  At some point, I might cover the insulation w/lauan - but this was simple and cheap enough.